# How to convert string to UTF-8 PHP

Tags: php, string, utf-8

how to change string into UTF 8 with rules like

1. i want Line Feed (LF) represent to be like %0A
2. Spaces represent +
3. CRLF (Carriage Return Line Feed) will return %0D%0A

example of the string

"
hello my name is david
and my friend is jessica.
"

and will return

"hello+my+name+is+robot%0Aand+my+friend+is+jessica"

hope u guys can help me

Comment: What has this got to do with UTF-8, why does david change to robot and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not UTF-8 Its urlencode..

There are urlencode function in php..

str = "hello my name is david and my friend is jessica."
urlencode($str)

Answer (score 0):

[urlencode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.urlencode.php) will do the trick

Check your string here https://www.tools4noobs.com/online_php_functions/urlencode/